# Verilog: More efficient way to use ternary operator

Tags: conditional-statements, verilog, assign, conditional-operator, hdl

I have written the following `assign` statement:

```
assign F = (BCD == 4'd1 | BCD == 4'd2 | BCD == 4'd3 | BCD == 4'd4 | BCD == 4'd5) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;
```

where if the `BCD` input (4-bits) is 1-5, the function returns a 1 and otherwise returns a 0. This works perfectly how I intended, but I'm looking for a more efficient way to write the "OR" parts. Is there a more efficient way to write this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for the ternary operator here. The result of each equality(`==`) is 1-bit, and you are doing a *bit-wise* OR (`|`). You probably should be using a *logical* OR (`||`) whose result is also 1-bit.

```
assign F = (BCD == 4'd1 || BCD == 4'd2 || BCD == 4'd3 || BCD == 4'd4 || BCD == 4'd5);
```

In SystemVerilog which most tools are supporting, you can use the inside operator

```
assign F = BCD inside {[1:5]}; //  contiguous range
assign F = BCD inside {[1:3],5, [7:10]}; //  noncontiguous values
```

Answer (score 2):

No, one should use each complete expressions separated by `|`. However, in this particular situation, you can use `(BCD >= 4'd1) & (BCD <= 4'd5)`.

Comment: You should use logical OR `||` not bitwise OR `|`

Comment: @dave_59 Indeed, here `||` should be used according to the standard. But I'd like to treat one-bit intermediate expressions as anonymous wires, and perform bit-wise operations.

Answer (score 1):

Since your values are in a continuous range, this can be simplified as:

```
assign F = ((BCD >= 4'd1) && (BCD <= 4'd5));
```

If your tool set supports SystemVerilog syntax, you could also use the `inside` operator.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 11.4.13 *Set membership operator*.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this:

a) Boundary check.

```
assign F = (BCD > 4'd0) & (BCD < 4'd6);
```

b) OR reduction and a high limit check.

```
assign F = |BCD & (BCD < 4'd6);
```

c) This is a behavioural hardware description, it would be optimized by the synthesis tool. It is parameterized, though.

```
localparam LOW = 1;
localparam HIGH = 5;
integer i;
reg F;
always @ (*) begin
  F = 1'b0;
  for(i = LOW; i <= HIGH; i = i + 1) begin: val_check
    if(BCD == i[3:0]) F = 1'b1;
  end
end
```